# Firefox Addon Development - no logs in console?

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-webextensions

Tried to write simple hello world addon, and my developer experience was no very nice.

Here is the source code of my addon.

`manifest.json`:

```
{
"name": "Foo Bar",
"version": "0.1.0",
"manifest_version": 2,
"developer": {
    "name": "Saša Stamenković",
    "url": "http://umpirsky.com"
},
"applications": {
    "gecko": {
        "id": "foo-bar@umpirsky.com"
    }
},
"background": {
    "scripts": ["background.js"]
},
"permissions": ["tabs", "storage", "notifications"]
}
```

`background.js`:

```
console.log('Hello World.');
```

I just wanted that "Hello World" text in my console, or to put it in other words, I wanted `background.js` to run.

First, I tried loading temporary addon from `about:debugging`:

[image]

What's wrong with my manifest?

Then, I tried `web-ext run`, no errors, but console was empty.

Am I missing something?

Comment: you should improve your question "Getting Started with Firefox Addon Development in 2018" is not a question, you should ask what you want to know in the headline

Answer (score 1, accepted):

None of those things happened to me

I copy pasted your code in my computer and worked just fine

I could see *Hello world* in browser console both times.

One thing that maybe is happening is that you are looking in Web Console instead of Browser Console.

*Load Temporary Add-on* is for loading directly the manifest.json file not the compiled xpi
If you want to load the xpi you should sign it:

> The generated .zip file doesn't work on Firefox without signing or adding applications.gecko.id key into manifest.json.  For more information, please refer WebExtensions and the Add-on ID page.

More info in:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/Getting_started_with_web-ext#Using_web-ext

Comment: Right, browser console, it's strange why `Hello World` is not printed in terminal with `web-ext run --verbose`. Thanks!

Comment: Unfortunately, I was able to open browser console only the first time. Every next try fails, it just does not react on menu press or `Ctrl + Shift + J` keypress. It works in the main window though, strange.

Comment: Browser toolbox has also the console embeded